# low current buck converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, low-power

Just trying to find a suitable buck converter for my application, which is running off ~10-50V (12/24/48V battery banks) and supplying normally a very low load microcontroller (~1mA) but occasionally doing some higher current SD writes (~150mA) and for some reason am unable to find something to meet these requirements.
Are these requirements too tight? Or is an output current range that wide and close to zero feasible?

Comment: [LM5009](http://www.ti.com/product/LM5009)?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I was originally thinking that, but the lack of documentation for low current (~1mA range) and from following the design procedure it seemed that it wasn't the correct chip for low current output, but I could definitely be incorrect there, do you have experience with this chip supplying low current reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this: -

[image]

[image]

Linear technology have a great search engine - you enter input voltage range, output (presumed to be 5V) and max load current and it comes up with recomendations.

It is the "50V" requirement that is the most problematic area for your design but do check TI to see what they can offer.